# Apache .htaccess URL rewriting is not working

Tags: htaccess, apache

I am using this code in *.htaccess* but the last line not giving any response:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user_pro.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$/images image.php?id=$1 [QSA,L] #this line not giving any response
```

Comment: $ in the last pattern will match a $ and not EOL

Comment: yes u r right @Aga . Can u tell what if user add a slash (/) after images like this `http://www.funnenjoy.com/foo/images/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `$` anchor signals the end of the subject (as `^` signals the start), thus your `expr` is incorrect.

What you're lookng for is more likely something like

```
# to rewrite images/foo to image.php?id=foo
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ image.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]

# to rewrite foo/images to image.php?id=foo
RewriteRule ^(.*)/images$ image.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

For more info have a look at [mod_rewrite intro](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex) and [the mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Comment: what if user types `foo/images/` than `foo/images` is working

Comment: you mean you want it to work whether there is a trailing slash or not? In that case you can use the `?`. e.g. `RewriteRule ^(.*)/images/?$ image.php?id=$1` would kick both `foo/images` and `foo/images/` to `image.php?id=foo`

Comment: thanks for reply and and good answer in above comment can this also work
`RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ user_pro.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]`  for `/foo` and for `/foo/`

Comment: Well, it would match, _but_ it would give you `foo` and `foo/` respecively as the IDs. Patterns like these are "greedy" meaning in this case the `.*` will match anything; the `/` included. If you want it to match anything _but_ a `/`, yet accept an optional trailing slash use `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ user_pro.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure mod_rewrite is on: 
*https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html*

1. If you're on a linux machine like Centos, you can check by running
   `httpd -l` to list compiled (installed) modules.
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337724/how-to-check-whether-mod-rewrite-is-enable-on-server

Lastly, are you including `RewriteEngine on` at the beginning of your code?

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ user_pro.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$/images image.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm not really familiar with the syntax, so I can't tell you whether `^(.*)$/images image.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]` is proper or not.